# How to choose the right flag to use when question can be flagged for multiple reasons?

Tags: discussion, flags

I came accross [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217502/create-a-nightclub-website-using-wordpress-or-php) which can be flagged for multiple reasons:

- **Off topic - "why isn't this code working?"** : OP doesn't explain how his piece of code is not working.
- **Off topic - "asking us to recommend..."** : OP explicitely demands us to recommand a plugin.
- **Unclear what you're asking** : it's pretty hard to tell what OP wants - assistance for the configuration of his metaslider plugin, or assistance for the navigation bar issue (which is unclear)?
- **Too broad** : from the title OP is basically asking us "how to do a website?" - even if he seems to narrow two problems he encounter that still isn't a "one question per problem" and the title is confusing.

I just flagged it as "unclear what you're asking", though I just pick that flag randomly from those four. Is there any way to choose the flag that need to be used (like a priority between flags), or maybe it doesn't matter, as long the question is flagged?

Comment: I'd say it's fairly clear what the person wants so I wouldn't use that. Either of the other two would be fine. There's not really any priority on the flag types as long as they are relevant. The only exception I would say is if closing as a dupe is a valid option. In those cases, that is usually better

Comment: I wouldn't say that "it is not working" is fairly clear, and the title as long as the "I want to do a website similar to this one" implies that there could be subsequent questions, as he want to replicate a website.

Comment: No, it's not extremely clear. But "unclear what you are asking" is often one that is least accepted, imo, because there is always those who think it is clear enough to give an answer even if they are just guessing

Comment: I voted "Too Broad" because the off-site resource request could be edited out and it would still be too broad.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Thanks for the link, based on it answer and codeMagic comment it seems the right answer is: it doesn't matter which flag I pick.

Comment: Well, it does matter. If the question is closed for a reason not the same as the reason you flagged then your flag is marked as disputed (not to be confused with declined). You should look at how the question can be edited to void each close reason and maintain the same original intent. If you can edit the post to void all close of the reasons, great! Edit the post and there is no longer a need to flag. If you end up with a close reason that can't be voided by an edit, flag for that reason.

Comment: Well the only flag that I can indeed avoid by editing is the plugin recommendation request as you said - I still end up with three reasonable flag reasons imo (I can't add debug informations, remove one of the two question or get in OP mind to understand what he exactly trying to do).